# How to secure PDF access in server and use PHP?

Tags: php, html, pdf, server

I just program a website with in the server a directory called "/src/PDF/" where all of my PDF documents are stored.
Actually I simply make a

```
<iframe class="mx-auto w-100" src="./src/PDF/mypdf.pdf#toolbar=0"></iframe>
```

to diplay it to the user, but any user can follow the link to "./src/PDF/" and access to all of my website's PDF !

You have to know that my website use account to access to the documents, so if you are a subscriber to the website or you acquired the PDF by unit,  you can see it, if not you have a page to connect, subscribe or acquir it individually.

I heared about .htaccess but I didn't find any formation to program .htaccess propely for my case.

Can a charitable soul come to my aid?
Thank you very much for your time !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have few options:

A) You put an index.html/index.php file in the directory. This could even be just a blank file. That way they don't see a directory listing.

B) You disable directory listing in your web server configuration, for Apache you can do this in an .htaccess file. Simply put in, or create an .htaccess file in `src/PDF/` with:

```
Options -Indexes
```

With either of these options however nothing will stop anyone from just guessing a name of a PDF file, or someone giving them a link to view it.

I would at the very least move the PDF files to a directly that cannot be accessed publicly (ie: before your public_html) and then use random file names and reference the actual name of the document from a database. Then send the PDF to the browser through a PHP script where only authenticated users can see it.